# correlation between the jumped distance ?!

Tags: statistics, correlation

[image]

Correlation analysis. “Sig. (2-tailed)” represents the p-value, and it is equal to 0.005; the
correlation between the jumped distance and the person’s height is highly significant

My question is about "the
correlation between the jumped distance and the person’s height is highly significant", what does it means?

Comment: They're referring to the statistically significant results this samples provides with respect to the hypothesis test $H_0:\rho=0$ versus $H_a:\rho \neq 0$ where $\rho$ is the population correlation coefficient measuring the strength of a linear association between explanatory and response variables. Note rejecting $H_0$ favors a linear association.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With such a large sample size, it might be surprising if you did not get a statistically significant result between things that look as if they might not be independent: age and length of stay in hospital are plausibly related, but then so too might age and length of stay in a holiday resort be.

"Highly significant" simply means that the $p$-value is very small.

Similarly it is plausible that taller people might on average be able to jump a little higher (or a lot higher) than shorter people on average, so with a large enough sample you might not be surprised by a highly significant result. At that stage, the important questions become "How much higher on average? and "How strong is the relationship?"

On the important question of whether a correlation of $r \approx 0.1$ is *substantial*, I would say a little but not very much: here is an invented possible plot of $1000$ points with $r \approx 0.1$ illustrating this

[image]

Comment: @user355834 - It is your original question, but I suspect your quotation is two different examples